# What did I forget when I created my function.php (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I developed my own Wordpress theme for the first time. When I install different plugins the javascript don't work. And I can't figure out why. I don't have any javascript files in my theme yet, that's why I havn't added any in the functions.php.

```
add_theme_support('menus');

function register_theme_menus() {

    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary-menu'  => __( 'Primary Menu', 'mymenu' )           
        )
    );

}

add_action( 'init', 'register_theme_menus' );


function wpt_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'googlefont_css', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,700,400italic,700italic' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_theme_styles' );


function twentysixteen_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Footer', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentysixteen_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: Please describe "don't work" in more detail.

Comment: Are you sure your theme is the culprit? This is important: [Debugging in WordPress « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: can you post your header.php file? you header.php file should have `wp_head();` before start the `body` tag